firework-js is not loading in html
I intend to integrate firework-js into simple html side, but the module is not loading.
Using Flask, the project is quite simple:
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html')

the index.html is like:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="fireworks-container"
      style="background-size: cover; background-position: 50% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
    <script type="module" src="{{url_for('static', filename='index.ts')}}"></script>
  </body>

</html>

The project structure is:

main.py
|--templates
|           |--index.html
|--static
|        |--index.ts

In the browser, there is a warning reporteing:

Module cannot be loaded: „http://127.0.0.1:5000/static/index.ts”.

Flask version:

Python 3.8.1
Flask 3.0.2
Werkzeug 3.0.1

As per my understanding, among the firework-js examples, either the "web" folder or the "with-web-components" folder might be useful, although none of them worked.
Shall the Typescript converted into Javascript to use in simple html-projects?
